# PHP creating a folder with the right path

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['editorpassword']) && isset($_POST['roomname'])) {
$dir = $_POST['filename']; // This must match the "name" of your input
$path = "evo/" . $dir;
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
}
}
?>
```

I have this script where I'm trying to create a new folder. The script itself is ran inside of a folder called /evo and by using this code, it creates the folder in there. Where it needs to go is ../../creative however even if I try and use

```
$path = "./rooms/creative/" . $dir;
```

or something to that effect it creates it with the base folder as evo so it appears at:

../evo/rooms/creative (creating the folders that don't exist there with it as it should)

I'm just unsure what to write in for the path on where I need it created to find the right location.

Comment: This is EXTREMELY dangerous!  DO NOT TRUST USER INPUT when messing around with your host machine's filesystem! `$_POST ["filename"] = "../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd"`

Comment: noted, though its not for users, it will be used by a couple of admins.

Comment: Maybe so but a) you shouldn't allow yourself to get into bad habits just because it's "not for public use" and b) you can't assume that anybody who shouldn't have access won't gain access somehow.  Also c) there's always the possibility that someone screws something up by mistake rather than by malice.

Comment: I agree Gordon thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to remove the "evo" in $path = "evo/" . $dir;

Comment: which creates it in the current directory, I wanted it done in another directory but I resolved it by moving the php file to the area I want to create the folders to cut down on confusion. Thank you.